# chrome extension problem with jquery .click() in table pagination

Tags: html, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I made a chrome extension that calculates the graduation average from the exam portal; the exams are contained in a table with pagination:

```html
 
<tfoot>
    <tr class="footable-paging">
        <td colspan="7">
            <div class="footable-pagination-wrapper">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="footable-page-nav disabled" data-page="first">
                        <a class="footable-page-link" href="#">«</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="footable-page-nav disabled" data-page="prev">
                        <a class="footable-page-link" href="#">‹</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="footable-page visible active" data-page="1">
                        <a class="footable-page-link" href="#">1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="footable-page visible" data-page="2">
                        <a class="footable-page-link" href="#">2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="footable-page-nav" data-page="next">
                        <a class="footable-page-link" href="#">›</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="footable-page-nav" data-page="last">
                        <a class="footable-page-link" href="#">»</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <span class="label label-default">Pagina 1 di 2, righe da 1 a 30 di 53 </span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

to navigate through the pages I used this jquery

```js
var $click = $('li[data-page="next"]').children();
$click[0].click();
```

in this way I was able to scroll through all the pages and recover all the exam marks.
For some time, however, the chrome extension is no longer able to change the page with this method, even if it always works from the browser console.
Can you tell me if there is a way to get the code in the chrome extension to work again or if there is a different method to retrieve the table data of all the pages?
Thanks

Comment: Please try changing $ with jQuery like this: var element = jQuery('li[data-page="next"]').children();
element[0].click();

Comment: unfortunately it does not solve the problem